# Audio recording in Python with Pyaudio, error ||PaMacCore (AUHAL)|| ... msg=Audio Unit: cannot do in current context

Tags: python, core-audio, pyaudio, macos-big-sur, portaudio

I am using pyaudio to record sounds on my Mac BigSur 11.6 (20G165). Specifically, I'm redirecting sound from an application to the input using BlackHole, which works fine.

It usually works fine but, sometimes, I get this error in the Terminal:

> ||PaMacCore (AUHAL)|| Error on line 2500: err='-10863', msg=Audio Unit: cannot do in current context

Any idea why or how I could prevent it from happening (like, waiting until PaMacCore is ready to record again or something)?

I already tried reinstalling but it doesn't help

```
brew install portaudio
```

or

```
brew install portaudio --HEAD
```

Here's my code:

```
import pyaudio
import wave


class Recorder(object):
    def __init__(self, fname, mode, channels,
                 rate, frames_per_buffer):
        self.fname = fname
        self.mode = mode
        self.channels = channels
        self.rate = rate
        self.frames_per_buffer = frames_per_buffer
        self._pa = pyaudio.PyAudio()
        self.wavefile = self._prepare_file(self.fname, self.mode)
        self._stream = None

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exception, value, traceback):
        self.close()

    def record(self, duration):
        # Use a stream with no callback function in blocking mode
        self._stream = self._pa.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16,
                                     channels=self.channels,
                                     rate=self.rate,
                                     input=True,
                                     frames_per_buffer=self.frames_per_buffer)
        for _ in range(int(self.rate / self.frames_per_buffer * duration)):
            audio = self._stream.read(self.frames_per_buffer)
            self.wavefile.writeframes(audio)
        return None

    def start_recording(self):
        # Use a stream with a callback in non-blocking mode
        self._stream = self._pa.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16,
                                     channels=self.channels,
                                     rate=self.rate,
                                     input=True,
                                     frames_per_buffer=self.frames_per_buffer,
                                     stream_callback=self.get_callback())
        self._stream.start_stream()
        return self

    def stop_recording(self):
        self._stream.stop_stream()
        return self

    def get_callback(self):
        def callback(in_data, frame_count, time_info, status):
            self.wavefile.writeframes(in_data)
            return in_data, pyaudio.paContinue

        return callback

    def close(self):
        self._stream.close()
        self._pa.terminate()
        self.wavefile.close()

    def _prepare_file(self, fname, mode='wb'):
        wavefile = wave.open(fname, mode)
        wavefile.setnchannels(self.channels)
        wavefile.setsampwidth(self._pa.get_sample_size(pyaudio.paInt16))
        wavefile.setframerate(self.rate)
        return wavefile
```

Usage example:

```
recfile = Recorder(filename, 'wb', 2, 44100, 1024)
recfile.start_recording()
...
recfile.stop_recording()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently the problem were mismatched bitrates in BlackHole's aggregated output device. I was aggregating Blackhole's output (44,1kHz) and the Mac Speakers (48kHz). This did not cause any consistent bad behaviour but sometimes led to these errors.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code, which works in my end.

```
def recording_by_pyaudio():
    chunk = 1024  # Record in chunks of 1024 samples
    sample_format = pyaudio.paInt32  # 16 bits per sample
    channels = 2
    fs = 44100  # Record at 44100 samples per second
    seconds = 4
    output = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "recording.wav")

    p = pyaudio.PyAudio()  # Create an interface to PortAudio

    print('Recording')

    stream = p.open(format=sample_format,
                    channels=channels,
                    rate=fs,
                    frames_per_buffer=chunk,
                    input=True)
    
    frames = []  # Initialize array to store frames
    # Store data in chunks for 3 seconds
    for i in range(0, int(fs / chunk * seconds)):
        data = stream.read(chunk)
        frames.append(data)

    # Stop and close the stream 
    stream.stop_stream()
    stream.close()
    # Terminate the PortAudio interface
    p.terminate()

    print('Finished recording')

    # Save the recorded data as a WAV file
    wf = wave.open(output, 'wb')
    wf.setnchannels(channels)
    wf.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(sample_format))
    wf.setframerate(fs)
    wf.writeframes(b''.join(frames))
    wf.close()
    return output
```